# Join Two Time Series with Different Domains in R

Tags: r, left-join

**Task**:

I occasionally need to left-join two time series that have different domains. The first is y(t) consisting of mostly-regular order pairs of data (ti, yi). The other is a set of labels and their start times (tj, Lj) at irregular intervals (plus one end time at the end). I join them by looping over every ti, finding the latest tj that is earlier than ti, then applying label Lj to (ti, yi) -> (ti, yi, Li).

Is there a more efficient, or readable, or elegant, or "R-style" way to perform a look-back join? Data and code follow. Thanks. I don't need working code or something that exactly matches my use case, just a concept I can research and maybe pseudocode.

**Data**:

y_of_t =

| time | value | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1003 | 6.3 |  |
| 2003 | 6.4 |  |
| 3002 | 6.7 |  |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 800003 | 7.2 |  |

LabelStartTimes =

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 15000 | B |
| 33000 | C |
| ... | ... |
| 750000 | K |
| 801000 | K |

(Every entry is a start time except the last entry which is an end time)

**Code**:

```
applyLabels <- function(y_of_t, LabelStartTimes) {
  # for each time value in y(t), find the most recent earlier time value in
  # LabelStartTimes then grab corresponding label
  y_of_t$Label <- NA
  for (i in 1:nrow(y_of_t)) {
    t_i <- y_of_t$time[i]
    #only if t_i is in range of t_j
    if (t_i >= min(LabelStartTimes$time) &
        t_i <= max(LabelStartTimes$time)) {
      LastPrevLabelTime <-
        max(subset(LabelStartTimes$time, LabelStartTimes$time < t_i))
      ChosenLabel <-
        LabelStartTimes$value[LabelStartTimes$time == LastPrevLabelTime]
      y_of_t$label[i] <- ChosenLabel
    }
  }

  return(y_of_t)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolling join!

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(y_of_t)
setDT(LabelStartTimes)

y_of_t[, label := LabelStartTimes[y_of_t, on = 'time', roll = TRUE, value]]
```

Comment: Checked: 20x faster. Thanks.